# Using multiple ports using Serialport NodeJS

Tags: node.js, serial-port, node-serialport

Trying to connect 5 serial devices to a nodeJS server with the SerialPort library.
Others have reported issues with more than 4 devices and I can't declare more than 3 ports without bringing down the entire server.
There doesn't appear to be a hard-coded limit, most likely a bug in the library.

Any alternative solutions would be welcome.

Comment: try posting the code you have wrote so far. maybe the issue is not in the library. cheers

Answer (score 0):

This was a [known issue with the library](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/issues/37).

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE.

The default size of the threadpool is 4, so if the serialport library is holding on to one thread per port, you will not be able to open more than 3 ports. (Opening a 4th port will block on all threads).

More information here: https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/on-problems-with-threads-in-node-js/